# Display Advanced Custom Field for Woocommerce applied to subcategory on parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have an advanced custom field set up to show on a woocommerce subcategory that allows the user to define a colour via the color picker field.

This field will apply that colour to a number of elements related to that sub category (Styling the sub category thumbnail, the product page itself etc).

Im currently using as per the the ACF documentation this code to pull the field in and display it on the subcategory page:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$color = get_field('colour', $term); // Get ACF Field
```

This works fine until it comes to the parent category for the sub pages. I am unable to call the field in for the sub categories of the parent. I understand I need to use get_terms(). I am unable ot get that working though.

This is some code I found which I have added to the loop on content-product_cat.php. However it just breaks the woocommerce loop. What would I need to do to this code to get the parent category page to show all the child subcategories each with its related color field?

```
// current term
$current_term = get_queried_object();

// child terms
// this returns an array of terms
$args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'YOUR TAXONOMY HERE',
  'parent' => $current_term->term_id,
  // you may need other arguments depending on your needs
);
$child_terms = get_terms($args);

// you need to maybe loop through the child terms gotte
// to pick which one you want to use
// I'm assuming that you only want to use the first one

$child_term = false; // set it to false to begin with
                     // we'll use this later
if ($child_terms) {
  $child_term = $child_terms[0];
}

// make a decision
if ($child_term) {
  // get field value(s) from child term
  $color = get_field('color', $child_term);
} else {
  // get field value(s) from current term
  $color = get_field('color', $current_term);
}

// do something with the values
echo $color;
```

Comment: I dont understand enough about it to know how to use it. Im limited by knowledge and look for examples to modify

Comment: It would appear my earlier comment was incorrect. Looks like you need the term object to pull in the field, not the term id. Did you have `'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',` in your $args instead of the placeholder 'YOUR TAXONOMY HERE'?

Comment: Yes, the product cat was replacec, it breaks the page at the point this code is entered

Comment: Okay, I looked through the woocommerce a bit more and I'm not exactly sure how to help with regard to this particular template. Just shooting in the dark here, what if you comment out your everything after you define `$current_term` and put in `var_dump(get_field('color', $current_term));` Does it return the field's proper value?

Comment: Just returns NULL

Comment: What if you `var_dump($current_term);` ? Is it still null?

Comment: Yes its still NULL

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/341632

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'wpse_add_custom_text_under_category_title', 10);

function wpse_add_custom_text_under_category_title($category) {
   $term_id = 'product_cat_'.$category->term_id;
   the_field('krotki_opis_kategorii', $term_id);
}
```

From Alex Uleberg:
get_queried_object_id on shop archive page it will return the id of the page and not the category. When you use the hook, the $category object will be passed in through the hook.